# I keep getting 0 as a result

Tags: java, eclipse, zero

This is for a school project where it I'm supposed to produce a program that calculates the total amount of money. I keep getting 0 as a result. What did I do wrong? Thanks!

```
package com.david.scanner;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class coin {
    public static void main (String[] Args){

        int quarters = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int nickels = 0;
        int pennies = 0;
        int totalCents = 0;
        int dollars = 0;
        int cents = 0;

        totalCents = (quarters*25 + dimes*10 + nickels*5 + pennies);
        dollars = (totalCents/100);
        cents = (totalCents%100);

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many quarters do you have -->");
        quarters = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many dimes do you have -->");
        dimes = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many nickels do you have -->");
        nickels = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many pennies do you have -->");
        pennies = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Quarters = " + quarters);         
        System.out.println("Dimes = " + dimes);         
        System.out.println("Nickels = " + nickels);
        System.out.println("Pennies = " + pennies);    
        System.out.println("Total value =" + dollars + "dollars " + cents + "cents!"); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Because you add them all before actually asking the user to enter their values. Move the `totalCents=...; dollars=...;cents=...;` after user input.

Comment: Suppressing warnings is not good. Just close the scanner ;)

Comment: If you are using java 7+, use `try(Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)){ /* rest of your code */ }`. Resource gets properly closed, and the warning disappears. win-win

Comment: My programming teacher has no idea what he's doing. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You made your calculations before you had your actual values.  Move

```
totalCents = (quarters*25 + dimes*10 + nickels*5 + pennies);
dollars = (totalCents/100);
cents = (totalCents%100);
```

after you accept your input and assign `quarters` through `pennies`, but before your final output.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code 
`totalCents = (quarters*25 + dimes*10 + nickels*5 + pennies);
        dollars = (totalCents/100);
        cents = (totalCents%100);`
after
`pennies = keyboard.nextInt();` line so that it gets the values you entered at command line
 Now Desired output is :

```
D:\>javac coin.java

D:\>java coin
How many quarters do you have -->3
How many dimes do you have -->
4
How many nickels do you have -->
5
How many pennies do you have -->
5
Quarters = 3
Dimes = 4
Nickels = 5
Pennies = 5
Total value =1dollars 45cents!
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to put your calculation B\W and it work

```
System.out.println("Quarters = " + quarters);         
System.out.println("Dimes = " + dimes);         
System.out.println("Nickels = " + nickels);
System.out.println("Pennies = " + pennies);     
totalCents = (quarters*25 + dimes*10 + nickels*5 + pennies);
dollars = (totalCents/100);
cents = (totalCents%100);
System.out.println("Total value =" + dollars + "dollars " + cents + "cents!");
```